# Spring sometimes throws ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException and other times OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a webapp I'm using Spring 4.3.9, and Hibernate 5.2.10 as JPA provider.

In a bean I have the following class and method:

```
    @Repository
    public class VentaDAO {

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager em;

      @Transactional
      public void tryAprobarPago(Decidir decidir) {
        long idAlmuerzoVenta = Long.parseLong(decidir.getSistemaClave());
        AlmuerzoVenta almuerzoVenta = em.find(AlmuerzoVenta.class, idAlmuerzoVenta);

        Almuerzo almuerzo = almuerzoVenta.getAlmuerzo();

        almuerzo.assignNroEntradas(almuerzoVenta);

        almuerzoVenta.setEstado(AlmuerzoVenta.Estado.APROBADA);
        almuerzoVenta = em.merge(almuerzoVenta);

        // force flush to detect potential version conflics BEFORE execute costly SQL operations
        em.flush();

        methodWithCostlySQLOperations();
      }
   }
```

When using optimistic locking AND there is a version conflict, the @Transactional method throws Spring's `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` when the database flush happens automatically after the method finishes execution, however if I insert a manual flush() in the middle, Spring does NOT intercept the JPA's `OptimisticLockException`?
This behavior makes optimistic locking handling problematic since the exception changes depending on how the method is codified.

I would prefer to handle only `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want Spring to do automatic error handling (exception translation) you need to annotate your class with `@Repository`

Comment: Yes, I do have the `@Repository` at class level.

Comment: `@Repository` will only work when you cross the boundary of the type with the annotation--Spring wraps it, so intramethod logic or same-object calls are unaffected.

Comment: Manual flush is done with bean managed transaction demarcation?

Comment: @GabrielBelingueres When class is annotated with `@Repository`, all methods are wrapped with the exception translation interceptor. Exception is then translated when method *returns*. If you flush inside method, the interceptor is not involved. Don't flush inside a `@Repository` annotated object.

Comment: @fg78nc Flushing early is fine inside a transaction. It can be used to keep memory footprint down in a very large transaction.

Comment: As suggested by other users, due to the limitation of Spring AOP Proxy calls within the same bean are not intercepted.

Comment: This do the trick but I don't like it:  try { .... }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
      DataAccessException dae = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(e);
      if (dae == null) {
        throw e;
      }
      throw dae;
    }